# I didn't tin my solder bit...now what?

Tags: soldering

In my haste to get soldering with my new iron (first time soldering in more than a decade...) I completely forgot to tin my bit.

Subsequently I've managed to part-tin it, but it's a bit of a mess.

Other than buying a new bit for the iron, do I have any other options?

[image: Partially-tinned bit]

Comment: Which iron is it? More particularly, how is the tip put together? That is, is it solid copper? Iron plated? ...

Comment: I'm not sure what type of bit it is, so have edited my question to include a picture.

Comment: It looks like it's plated, so try to scrape off the crud while it's hot and use lots of flux-cored solder to tin it while you're scraping it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice...scrape off with a blade, or wire wool...?

Comment: I usually use an edge of the blade of a slotted screw screwdriver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether the untinned tip coating is just covered with a layer of crud, like flux residue, or is now all oxidized.  If the former, you can probably carefully clean it off (with the iron cold, of course), then power it up and tin it properly.  If the latter, this is a unrecoverable error and the part of the tip you didn't tin is now useless.

Comment: If its all oxidised couldn't you remove the tip and immerse it in vinegar? If my chemistry doesn't fail me, the acid base reaction should remove the oxide layer and then you can do as you please.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry, those things happen sometimes. It's worth it to buy a soldering tip refresher if you use that quite often.

For a fast home solution, you can use [solder wick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desoldering#Desoldering_braid)/ flux/ solder to solve this:

1. Put enough flux on the solder wick.
2. You may need someone to help you hold the solder wick. Make sure it doesn't move.
3. Heat the tip and scratch the solder tip on the solder wick while you apply solder.

Soon you will find your tip is back to life!

Answer (score 1):

How long has it been turned off? I think you'll be fine. I will sometimes use some of the tip tinner & cleaner from radio shack. It will partially renew the tip.

Comment: I think RadioShack went out of business a while ago, so that might be a minor issue.

Comment: Yeah they're not doing too good. Still available here thankfully. They never try to sell me cell phones and know I'm heading straight back to the component trays.

Comment: @haneefmubarak Radioshack is closing, not out of business yet. Presently in fire-sale.

Comment: @EJP huh. All the locations near where I love have all closed up and removed the signs already.

Comment: @user214880 so do they have sales on components now or are they still a ripoff?

Comment: Some good discounts, mostly ripoffs. But sometimes I just "need" something for the current project.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a solid copper tip, let then iron cool down, file new faces on it, turn it on, and then tin it as it heats up. If it's plated, what works for me is to flood the tip with flux-cored solder while the iron is hot, and then to use the edge of a flat-bladed screwdriver to lightly scrape the damaged area while the iron is hot, while applying fresh solder.